# Are there two isomorphic transitive subgroups of $\mathfrak{S}_n$ that are not conjugate?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, monodromy

I know that we can find two subgroups of $\mathfrak{S}_6$ both isomorphic to $\mathfrak{S}_5$ that are however not conjugate ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383676/s-6-contains-two-subgroups-that-are-isomorphic-to-s-5-but-are-not-conjugate)) in $\mathfrak{S}_6$. These subgroups are not conjugate precisely because one and only one of them is transitive.

Can we find two *transitive* subgroups of a symetric group that are isomorphic but not conjugate ?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206287/are-there-two-isomorphic-subgroups-of-the-symmetric-group-of-a-countable-set-whi), item 2.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for a group with two core-free subgroups of the same order that are not equivalent under an automorphism of the group.

For example, we could take the subgroups $\langle (1,2)  \rangle$ and $\langle (1,2)(3,4) \rangle$ of $S_4$. The actions on the cosets of these subgroups give rise to two transitive subgroups of $S_{12}$ that are isomorphic to $S_4$, but not conjugate in $S_{12}$.

Or, we could take the subgroups $\langle (1,2,3,4) \rangle$, $\langle (1,2),(3,4) \rangle$ of $S_4$ to get an example in $S_6$.

Comment: Ok but why these two transitive subgroups of $S_{12}$ are then not conjugate ?

Comment: If they were conjugate, conjugation would map one point stabilizer isomorphically to the other one.